# ruby module structure insight

Tags: ruby, module, package

I'm new to Ruby and i'm making a Ruby package. 
structure is:

```
eventsims (main folder)
  |__lib
     |__eventsims {subfolder)
     |  |__discrete.rb
     |  |__randgen.rb
     |  |__simevent.rb
     |  |version.rb
     |__eventsims.rb
```

If i put all the codes in my three modules file (discrete, randgen and simevent) in the ["Eventsims" module inside the eventsims.rb file], it is easy but there would be up to 1000 lines of code which I don't want

Now I have a "require" lines of code inside eventsim.rb that requires all these four files in the eventsim subfolder.

I can use all the modules, no errors. 
for example in the discrete.rb, a module called Discrete with a Calculate class having an expectval method:

Is this how I would be able to use the package after installing it with Rubygems

```
require "Eventsims"
a = Discrete::Calculate.new([1,0,4,2], [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0])
a.expectval()
```

and if yes, is it sensible to have it that way because so many modules I've seen will have something like:

```
require "eventsims"
Eventsims::someclass.new
```

which in my case would be
    require "eventsims"
    Discrete::someclass.new

I'm worried about the consistency of the required file and its namespacing. require **eventsim** and its different **Discrete**

Sorry the question is really long.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some other languages, Ruby does not tie the filesystem names to module hierarchy. If you *want* to have `require "eventsims"` provide the module `Discrete`, you *can*. Whether or not it's a good idea, it is for you to decide - Ruby is not your Mum. There are two potential pitfalls:

- Gem users might get confused, and wonder how to use your gem
- Someone in some other gem also defines `Discrete` and you have a collision.

A compromise between the two approaches (having a distinct namespace and having less to type) is to indeed have a top module `EventSims`, and for users to `include` it if they want to access the next level down directly:

```
# safe usage
require 'eventsims'
EventSims::Discrete::Calculate.new

# easy usage
require 'eventsims'
include EventSims
Discrete::Calculate.new

# restricted easy usage
require 'eventsims'
module MyCode
  include EventSims
  Discrete::Calculate.new
end
EventSims::Discrete::Calculate.new
```

This way, you still have namespacing, and you can get rid of it when you know there is no collision in your code. Going the other way around (having no namespacing and trying to isolate the code when a collision *does* happen) is significantly more difficult.

Comment: from your bottom example can I use the Eventsim module in the three different files i mean. same module name in three different files

Comment: Yup. Ruby has no problems reopening already defined classes or modules for further modification. You will need `module EventSims; module Discrete; ... end; end` or similar in each file; alternately, `module EventSims; end` in the top file (`eventsims.rb`), then you can use `module EventSims::Discrete; ... end` in individual files.